# Interpolated map using pca axes

Tags: r, kriging, eigen-values

I have done between group pca in R. I want to make an interpolated map using the eigen values of the first three pc axes.

I want to produce a map using each of the three pc axes and finally combine the three maps to produce a final interpolated map.

Comment: This is too general a question to give much useful advice. See perhaps the [guerry](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Guerry/index.html) r package and associated vignette for some examples. Also see [this answer by whuber](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/37410/751) to a different question (that gives extension r tutorials of PCA - albeit geographically weighted PCA).

Comment: Most of this sounds routine when you break it into its component steps: your PCA produces an ordered triple of eigenvalues at a discrete set of sample points.  You will interpolate them (separately or with a vector procedure such as cokriging) onto three grids. What is unclear is how you propose to "combine" those three grids. Could you perhaps indicate the purpose of this exercise?

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you are looking for is the adegenet-spca package, that lets you interpolate principal components:

http://adegenet.r-forge.r-project.org/files/adegenet-spca.pdf